# Apache wildcard subdomain rewrite with Angular app

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess, angular-router

I have an Angular app that needs to run under a subdomain for multi-tenant support. Every subdomain is a different tenant under the app.
For now I have current .htaccess setup that does the work for (only) loading the main page, but actual Angular routing does not work at all.

Current .htaccess looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /manager
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.io
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.domain\.io [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !manager/
RewriteRule (.*) /manager/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

There is also a WP site on the main domain, hence the WordPress entries.

What I want to achieve is whenever someone goes to SUBDOMAIN.domain.io it loads the files from `/manager` folder without rewriting address and then allows for angular routing to work, so when someone goes to `subdomain.domain.io/admin` it will load the angular route.

Is this possible? If yes, then could someone suggest a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your complete .htaccess may work like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)[^.]+\.domain\.io$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^manager/ manager%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(index\.php$|manager/) - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

It is important to place `manager` rule before WP front controller rule.

- `(?!www\.)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if host name start with `www.`.
- `RewriteRule !^manager/ manager/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]` will execute only if URI doesn't start with `/manager/`

Comment: Unfortunately this one indeed doesn't redirect back to main domain, but returns ```Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.```

Comment: Can you check your apache error.log and let me know what is error there

Comment: The edited version works now, the one I commented on looked different. Will mark that as an answer. Thanks for quick responses!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the issue in the official docs? https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration - there're some examples (including apache) of how routed apps must fallback to index.html.
Here's also another .htaccess example that I've used in one of my apps:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```